# How to Load 100 million rows csv into relational db MySql using node js within less than 10 minutes

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, relational-database

I have one csv file it contains 100 million rows with 10 columns.
Currently it takes more than 1 hour to load 100 millions of rows.
To load CSV using Node JS into MySql DB, I used batch processing and node js stream features.

Hi
I want to load that 100 million rows into MySql db using node js within less than 10 minutes, because I have 70 CSV and each contains minimum 100 million row.
Please provide some guidance or reference links.
If you are suggesting any other relational db then it works for me.
Only requirement is it should load 100 millions rows CSV less than 10-15 minutes.

Hardware Configuration:-
Intel Xenon 8 core processor
RAM 16 GB

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=node+load+large+MySql+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.